# Issues when animating a simple Container View

Tags: swift, core-animation

Here is the inital setup:

[image]

I have 4 constraints on the UIView...see image below.

When I go to animate it with

```
@IBOutlet weak var leadingCon: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self.leadingCon.constant = -100
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

It slides it off to the side however...it also adjusts the bottom margin. It starts larger then needed and then animates down to the 30....not sure why.

Top Margin[image: Contraints]

Comment: Please show the constraints more fully including the other container view contraints and the cut-off "Leading Con" constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to perform an animation in `viewDidLoad` is pretty much asking for trouble. It's way too early. Your views are not even in the interface, so the user is not going to see any animation anyway. Plus, your views do not yet have any meaningful size / position! Wait until at least after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so that your views can assume their initial position and size before you perform an animation. Even better, wait until `viewDidAppear` so that the user sees the initial position followed by the animation.